# ASP.net Button on click not firing using Jquery Modal Dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a div that is shown as a Modal dialog.

```
<div id="div2" style="display: none;" title="Upload Prenda">
        <center>
            <br />
            Select File to Upload:
            <asp:FileUpload ID="PrendaFileUpload" runat="server" Width="345px" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PrendaFileUpload"
                ErrorMessage="File to be uploaded Required" ValidationGroup="X">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True"
                ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="X" />
            <br />
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="uploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadButton_Click"
                 Width="100px" />
        </center>
    </div>
```

here is the jquery for it

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#div2" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal:true,
resizable: false,
 height: 200,
width: 600
});
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
$( "#div2" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>
```

the problem is after i press the button to activate the `OnClick="uploadButton_Click"` the method inside does not fire, any fix for this? sorry im just new in using jquery.

Comment: I think you will find that the problem is that jQuery dialogs are done is such a way that removes them from the normal ASP.NET form tags. I had this problem about a year ago and can't remember exactly what I did, or where I found the answer. Pretty sure it was on this site somewhere.

If I can find it I will update this with a link to the answer. There was a pretty simple fix, it's just tricky to find.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well this is the answer that worked for me, im not using any update panel and this is what i used

adding this to the dialog declaration:

```
  open: function(type,data) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
  }
```

found the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718775/2705620) so if you want to know more about click the link beside :)

Answer (score 3):

The newer versions of JQueryUI use a slightly different convention.  In your `.dialog()` declaration, add this is a parameter:

```
appendTo: "form",
```

This fixes the issue for new versions of JQuery, since it builds the dialog box outside the scope of the ASP.NET form.  Hope this helps newer users!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:
[jQuery modal dialog with postbacks in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636907/jquery-modal-dialog-with-postbacks-in-asp-net)

This tells jQuery to append the dialog to the form tag rather than the end of the document.

Comment: @TylerDurden the solution above did not work for me, im using 1.8 jquery UI

Comment: @user2705620 apologies but I only just now got notified of this comment. I am assuming that you have solved this issue by now? ;)

Answer (score 1):

This query will fire C# code from JQuery. I tested it:

```
 $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```