# how to use jquery Dialog (popup) in user control asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i would like to make a popup dialog box when a user click on a button with user control in asp.net but i keep failing as the dialog box does not open at all. 
here is what i have in my .ascx file:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>some text here</p>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

and here is what i have in my .aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript">    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnR" runat="server" Text="Requirements" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right" />
</asp:Content>
```

and i have jquery 1.11.0 min in my materpage
so what am i doing wrong that the dialog box does not popup?
thank you in advance

Comment: i hope that you have closed </script>

Comment: If you want to open the dialog on the button click event you have to make sure that the button doesnt fire a postback with return false to cancle the postback.

Comment: @Daniele94 : yes i have...its just a missing tag while posting

Comment: @RandRandom : how can i make it Ispostback?

Comment: You should prevent the postback like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button

Comment: @RandRandom : i changed it to :                 <asp:Button ID="btnR" runat="server" Text="Requirements" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right" OnClientClick="return false;"/>  and its still not working!!!

Comment: Because you arent executing the script thats opening the dialog on button click...

Comment: @RandRandom <asp:Button ID="btnR" runat="server" Text="Requirements" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="dialog(); return false;"/>  and still not working!!

Comment: hey, maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14638951/3806089) can help you, let us know please ;)

Answer (score 0):

your script should look like:

```
function dialog(){
    $("#dialog").dialog();
};
```

your button should be

```
<asp:Button ID="btnR" runat="server" Text="Requirements" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="dialog(); return false;" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReqPopup.ascx.cs" Inherits="IRELBS.Mod.WebUserControl1" %>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>some text here</p>
</div>
<script>
    $(function dialog() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
</script>

Comment: does the above statement not work? btw you dont need the "$(" in your script

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReqPopup.ascx.cs" Inherits="IRELBS.Mod.WebUserControl1" %>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>some text here</p>
</div>
<script>
    function dialog() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    };
</script>
 and still it doesnt work!

Comment: wait, where should i use my <uc1:ReqPopup runat="server" ID="ReqPopup" /> to import my ascx file exactly??